# Directive's onInit method is called many times when the parent element is hidden and shown again

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, ngoninit

```html
<div *ngIf="variable">
    <directive></directive>
</div>
```

In the above code snippet (Angular 2), I change the variable from `true` to `false` and hence the directive won't render and next when i try to set variable to true again, `onInit` is called from the directive one more time.

I want the ngOnInit method to be called during the loading of directive for the first time only.

Why my ngOnInit of directive is called everytime when the variable value changes from false ngOnInit true.

Any suggestions.

Comment: need full code snippet

Comment: *ngIf is an structural directive which changes the DOM on change of value it wraps up. That is the reason NgOninit is called everytime value changes

Comment: `ngOnInit` is ran when the component is created.

Since you create and destroy it with your `*ngIf`, the component is being created several times. 

If you want a special behavior, I suggest you explain what it is, so that we can give you some advice about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of use `*ngIf` use `[hidden]="variable"`.

When you use `*ngIf` you're removing the element from the `DOM` and once you toggle it to true again it'll render the directive again.

Also, I recommend you to take a look at the *hidden* [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) for possible CSS issues.

Comment: Thanks Luiz and all for the valuable input, now got understood why my ngOnInit called mutliple times, fixed it by avoiding *ngIf and instead used [hidden].